# implementing strace with compatibility for the clone() syscall

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, strace, ptrace

how would I get my program to ptrace a cloned application as from the output it appears to execute a clone() syscall but I am not sure how I would ptrace it, could anyone help me, if possible provide a working minimal example as proof that such would work

```
SYSCALL pipe() IS NOT YET SUPPORTED

system call (end) (call number: 22) pipe (with return: 0) from pid 7596
SYSCALL clone() IS NOT YET SUPPORTED

system call (end) (call number: 56) clone (with return: 7597) from pid 7596
...
ATTEMPTING TO READ SYSTEM CALL rt_sigsuspend argument 1 (REGISTER: rdi)
ORIGINAL system call (start) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend(140734241713168, 8) from pid 7596
TRANSLATED system call (start) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend("", 8) from pid 7596
zsh: command not found: q

system call (end) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend (with return: -514) from pid 7596
ATTEMPTING TO READ SYSTEM CALL rt_sigsuspend argument 1 (REGISTER: rdi)
ORIGINAL system call (start) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend(140734241713168, 8) from pid 7596
TRANSLATED system call (start) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend("", 8) from pid 7596

system call (end) (call number: 130) rt_sigsuspend (with return: -38) from pid 7596

help
exit
^C
^Z
```